# Can I "while=test" results in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I'm building a complex SQL query and I want to test a result in a while statement.

I want to do something like:

```
WHERE ( R.Expired IS NULL OR R.Expired > SYSDATE )
  AND (
    CASE
      WHEN R.Description LIKE '%SSX%' THEN TRUE
      ELSE  FALSE
    END
  ) ORDER BY R.Name
```

But PL/SQL says it has some "invalid relational operator" (translated).

Is there something wrong with my CASE statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `CASE WHEN` stuff looks unnecessary to me.

Just use

```
AND (R.Description Like '%SSX')
```

First rule of debugging - *avoid unnecessary complexities.*

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve here, but you can perhaps try enclosing TRUE and FALSE in single quotes (as booleans are not supported in SQL) or simply write something like `AND R.Description LIKE '%SSX%'`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple:

```
WHERE (R.Expired IS NULL OR R.Expired > SYSDATE) AND 
      R.Description LIKE '%SSX%'
```